# How do i select a column without using indexing

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, indexing

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | 2 | 3 |
| Singapore | 2 | 3 |

After running for col in df.values.tolist():
i get:

Africa 2 3

Singapore 2 3
.
.
.

to capture each column (e.g. 2,2 for column A), i cant seem to capture the column names as col['A'] as it will be give me an error message "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

instead i have to use col[0] den it will give me 2,2 .

Is there any other way to script this to write col['A'] instead? just for traceability/easier on the eyes for reviewer that i am pulling column with description A instead of having to refer to the df and seeing what column[0] refers to

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: You are iterating a list, as such numerical indexing is used. You probably want to iterate through the dataframe itself

Comment: hi @sammywemmy thanks for helping! are u able to elaborate a little on this?

Comment: Hey @Corralien
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5197 entries, 0 to 5196
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                        --------------  -----  
 0   country_name                  5197 non-null   object 
 1   industry_group               5197 non-null   object 
 2   count of abc                    5197 non-null   int64  
 3   count of xyz                     5195 non-null   float64

Comment: As @sammywammy said, I think you just need: `for col in df.columns:` and then inside loop just `print(df[col])`

Answer (score 0):

use `.to_dict('records')`

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [10, 20, 30], 'C': [111, 222, 333]})
for col in a.to_dict('records'):
    print(f"{col['A']=}\t{col['B']=}\t{col['C']=}")
```

[image]

Comment: hey there! thanks for getting back, i might not have been very clear with my qns and added some details to clarify!